# Login window shows as white after button press

Tags: facebook, ios5, xcode4.3, xmppframework

I am creating a ios facebook application using facebook sdk-2010.In which Graph-Api is used for getting friends list.XMPP is used for the chat.
After giving the user name and password in the facebook login window, log in window not disappears and not get log in some times.Some times log in window won't be comming in the simulator.From last week onwards some times the app shows the above problems.The app was running properly till last week.Today morning I have runned the app with same code,but now I am getting these error,net connection is available while checking.If any body having idea then please help me
[image: here i am attaching the screen shot of the error]